# Posting back to website from a Java Web Start app?

Tags: java, http-post, java-web-start

Is there any way to post back to a website from a Java Web Start App ?  Here is what I'm trying to accomplish. I have an website with a page to place orders online. I've designed a JWS app that can read barcodes from a little scanner that we use for another ordering software.  I'm trying to make it so I can start the Java app from the website and read the scanner, then send the barcode data back to the website to fill in the order so they don't have to hand key the order into the website.  Trying to figure out the best way to accomplish this and not sure what all Java is capable of doing.

Comment: Have you considered reading the barcodes directly into the web page? Barcode readers usually type in the barcode string just like someone typing on the keyboard.

Comment: What we are using doesn't, they are little key fob like scanners that store the barcodes in memory until you connect them to a computer and have a program that reads the scanner data.  Your thinking more of the type of scanners they use for scanning barcodes at a cash register which have to be constantly wired to the computer.

Comment: *"Is there any way to post back to a website from a Java Web Start App ?"  Yes.  It is done the same way for a web-start app. as for an app. with no GUI.  So put 'web start' out of your mind for the moment and figure out how to do a post from an app. based on the command line.

Comment: Continuing Andrew Thompson comment, you'll be able to post to the server, no to the web page where te app was initiated. But the webpage could poll the server for new data. Is that good enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

A Java Web Start app can post data to the server, either using any http client library or manually with [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html).

A Java Applet can [manipulate the DOM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/manipulatingDOMFromApplet.html) of the webpage where it's included.